# Questions about the frequency table in arithmetic encoding compression

Tags: compression, lossless-compression

I have a high level idea of how arithmetic coding works, but in the sources I've read (https://neptune.ai/blog/lossless-data-compression-using-arithmetic-encoding-in-python-and-its-applications-in-deep-learning and https://go-compression.github.io/algorithms/arithmetic/) it's not clear to me what the relationship between the frequency table and the message we're compressing is.

My understanding is the frequency table is determined from some universe of messages, and thus should be representative of messages you'll encode, in expectation. Is this understanding correct?

My second question pertains to why characters with larger frequencies (and thus larger probabilities) take up a large section of the interval. I don't believe this has anything to do with accuracy. Does it somehow speed up the algorithm? Why not make every character have the same probability?

Answer (score 1):

I start with the second question: no, it has nothing to do with speed. Using the probabilities is the very thing **that actually does the compression!**

The main idea of the compression: use few bits for common messages, and use many bits for rare messages. In the ideal case, we should use exactly 1 bit for a message with 50% probability. So compression actually crucially depends on knowing the frequencies.

Arithmetic coding implements almost ideal coding - it produces a bit for each time a probability range is reduced by half. Low probability symbols produce a smaller range - so they output more bits. High probability symbols produce less bits. Symbols with probability >50% may produce no bits - it would take several such symbols for a single bit!

There are many ways to calculate a frequency table - but it should match the real distribution of the input as close as possible. The closer they are - the better compression you would get. Note, that *both encoder and decoder must use the same frequencies!*

- You could just pre-calculate the expected frequencies and hardcode them into both encoder and decoder. However, beware - if the input doesn't follow expectations - you'll get no compression, or even get an "expansion"!
- You could calculate frequencies from the input, and pass the values to the decoder. Of course, storing the table will increase the compressed size.
- You could calculate the frequencies from the previous input, and live-update them as you compress. Arithmetic coding allows changing frequencies at any time.

Comment: In your second bullet, "you could calculate frequencies from the input..." is this the adaptive variant where you compute frequencies/probabilities on the fly?

Comment: @24n8 No, adaptive variant is the third one. In the second, you preprocess the entire input, and then store the frequency table in the output.

Comment: Sorry, I meant third bullet. In which case would you use the 3rd over the 2nd? It seems like it terms of compression efficiency, #2 is better since it gives you the actual distribution of the characters you're compressing?

Comment: I think https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127347/adaptive-arithmetic-coding-confusion answers that question

Comment: I might start a new question for this but I was looking at the implementation in https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/adaptive-arithmetic-coding and I don't quite understand the `while len(output) < cur_out_len + digits:` loop.